# How can I get the timestamp for a given day of week?

Tags: php, timestamp, weekday

Basically, I have this requirement to convert a present/future weekday to a timestamp.

Example:

```
today     = Thu, 24 Feb 2010
weekday   = Tue
next date = Tue,  1 Mar 2010
cur stamp = 1267016400
new stamp = 1267448400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime('Tue')` will return the timestamp of the next Tuesday.

`strtotime('Tue', $time)` will return the timestamp of the next Tuesday from the given timestamp.

Comment: Uhm...(duh!) Don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with:

```
/**
 * @param $weekday string The weekday in short (3 letter) format, eg: "Mon" or "Tue".
 * @return integer The calculated timestamp.
 */
function next_weekday_to_stamp($weekday,$today=null){
    if(!$today)$today=time();
    $range = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');
    $days = array_search(date('D'), $range);
    $range = array_slice($range, $days);
    $days = array_search($weekday, $range);
    return strtotime('+'.$days.' days', $today);
}
```

Talk about over-engineering it out!

Anyway, if someone wants to use this in the past (last weekday), it can be easily adapted.

Comment: As Lacking Ideas pointed out, 'strtotime("Tue")' should do what you want - return either today (if it's currently Tuesday) or the next Tuesday (if it's any other day of the week)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
strtotime("+7 days", strtotime("Thu, 24 Feb 2010"))
```